# .Net Core Logging "Input string was not in a correct format." Message

Tags: logging, .net-core

I'm running a .Net Core Azure Function with the following logging logic:

```
        private void LogException(Exception ex, string funcName)
        {
            _logger.LogError($"Error while executing {funcName}: ex.Message", ex);
        }
```

and receiving this exception:

**Input string was not in a correct format.**

The exception I'm trying to log, received from a REST call, has this message:

**{"statusCode":401,"error":"Unauthorized","message":"Invalid token","attributes":{"error":"Invalid token"}}**

So my question is: do I have to escape all brackets sent to a Logxxx method? Is there a way to disable this "feature"?

Comment: Just as a hint: ```_logger.LogError(ex, $"Error while executing {funcName}: {ex.Message}");``` is the correct way calling the "LogError". [see documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.loggerextensions.logerror?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0#Microsoft_Extensions_Logging_LoggerExtensions_LogError_Microsoft_Extensions_Logging_ILogger_System_Exception_System_String_System_Object___)

Answer (score 1):

It would help if I used the correct signature:

```
_logger.LogError(ex, $"Error while executing {funcName}: {ex.Message}");
```

Comment: thank you. The fact that usually its error then text and that the OP syntax does not throw an error make this very very easy to miss.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this old post as a top result when looking into [CA2254](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca2254).  Both this and the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/logging?tabs=command-line#log-message-template-formatting) would suggest using structured templates.

```
e.g. _logger.LogError(ex, "Error while executing {FunctionName}: {ExceptionMessage}", funcName, ex.Message);
```

Then those names can be exposed in the logging UI.  One note, the exception will already log the exception message so you could use

```
e.g. _logger.LogError(ex, "Exception while executing {FunctionName}", funcName);
```

And chances are the call stack would identify the function so maybe just in this case, just log the exception.

but..wait, the function can log unhandled exceptions...so maybe no code needed at all.